# Two provisioning profiles of same name with different expiry dates

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, profile, provisioning-profile

I have released an ABC app through enterprise distribution. When one of my client loaded restore from his previous phone, the backup included the profile for ABC and when he reinstalled ABC on his new phone it added the profile of same name again with different expiry date.Now his phone has two profiles of same name with different expiry dates. I am not getting what may be the reason behind this case?

Comment: first remove both of profile and then after add one profile

Comment: @DarshanKunjadiya I want in which case this might happen. App is installing without any error.

Comment: so continue with both are :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check on the https://developer.apple.com

This may be because there are two provisioning profiles with the same name one created by you and the other one is managed by Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple instances of the same provisioning profile.  I have not seen any instances where this causes problems, as long as you have at least one non-expired provisioning profile that supports the bundle id of the app being installed. We have devices that have 4 or 5 of the same provisioning profile on them, just because we generate a new one any time we get a new device.

Typically, I just delete the one with the older expiration date, or wait until one expires and delete it then. It sounds like you are not having any problems, so are you just asking out of curiosity, or fear that it will cause a problem down the road?